# Using an array as a chessboard, how can I code a loop that will detect available moves

Tags: matlab, chess

I'm currently working through a game of Hexapawn (A 3 by 3 Chessboard game with each player having 3 pawns) using MATLAB. Currently, I am using an array that represents the chessboard (chessboard = [1 1 1; 0 0 0; 2 2 2];) :

1         1        1

0         0        0

2         2        2

The 1s represent player 1's pawns, the 0s represent empty spaces, and the 2s represent player 2's pawns. Default chess rules apply to these pawns where they can only move one space ahead, and can only attack pawns directly diagonal to them. I'm unsure of how I can write a loop so that I can inform the user of his available moves depending on where his pawns are on the board.

My current code is here:

```
%% START OF GAME

start_input = input('Would you like to play a game of Hexapawn? Y/N : ', 's');
while strcmpi(start_input, 'Y') == 0 && strcmpi(start_input, 'N') == 0
    start_input = input('ERROR: PLEASE ANSWER WITH THE AVAILABLE RESPONSES : ', 's');
end

%% GAMEPLAY
if strcmpi(start_input, 'Y') == 1
    fprintf('\n')
    % CHESSBOARD BASIC
    chessboard = [1 1 1; 0 0 0; 2 2 2];
    disp(chessboard)


else
    fprintf('Goodbye!')
end
```

Comment: @Brett Oh right, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer to your question.  The function below will take a current board arrangement, and a given pawn.  Then determine if that single Pawn has available moves.  It will return a logical matrix the size of the board

Example for the given board check the upper left pawn.

```
board = [1 1 1;...
         0 2 0;...
         2 0 2];
pawn = [1 0 0;...
        0 0 0;...
        0 0 0];
>> [availMoves] = checkMoves(board,pawn)

availMoves = 
    3x3 logical array
    0   0  0
    1   1  0
    0   0  0
```

So you can see that upper left pawn can move straight down or diagonally to take an enemy.

Example: same board but check the #2 pawn in the center:

```
pawn = [0 0 0;...
        0 2 0;...
        0 0 0];
>> [availMoves] = checkMoves(board,pawn)
availMoves = 
    3x3 logical array
    1   0  1
    0   0  0
    0   0  0
```

That pawn can move up at diagonals ...

So with this function you could loop over a player's pawns on the board, OR each of their pawns moves together, and then see if the returned matrix contained anything  ex.  `if ~any(availMoves);disp('You Lose!');end`  or similar.

```
function [availMoves] = checkMoves(board,pawn)
%Check if a given pawn can move or not
%Returns a logical matrix the size of the board for that pawns moves.

%Init output    
availMoves = false(size(board));   

%Get Pawn in question's current r,c position
[pR,pC] = find(pawn);  

%Determine pawn's relative forward movement.  If pawn is a 1 then
%"forward" means increase row. IF pawn is a 2 then "forward" is a decrease.
fwdDir = (pawn(~pawn==0) == 1)*1 + (pawn(~pawn==0) == 2)*-1;

%At the edge already so no available moves. 
fwdR = pR+fwdDir;
if fwdR > 3 || fwdR <0
    return % Return all false.
end

%Pawn can step directly forward if empty.   
availMoves(fwdR,pC) = board(fwdR,pC) == 0;  %Space is empty 

%Get the # of the enemy pawn.  If current is 1 then enemy is 2 etc
enemyPawn = 2*(pawn(~pawn==0) == 1) + 1*(pawn(~pawn==0) == 2);

%Pawn can step diagonal if occupied by enemy. 
fwdC = [pC+1 pC-1];
fwdC(fwdC > 3 | fwdC <= 0) = []; %kill moves outside of the board
availMoves(fwdR,fwdC) = board(fwdR,fwdC) == enemyPawn;  %Space has enemy
```

Answer (score 0):

Add n matrices with the same size as your chessboard which each shows one possible  move. Maybe like a 1 where the current figure is and a 3 where he can move to.

Each move can be calculated by getting the indices of the current figure and checking if he can move upwards/sidewards (as long as he doesn't get out of bounds). I would suggest you mirroring the chessboard with [flipud](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) so you can use the same rules for both players.